# Animate a square and arrow using matplotlib animate and patches

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, animation

I want to animate the location and velocity of the robot using a rectangle and the arrow in jupter notebook. The rectangle patch represents the location of robot on the grid and arrow the velocity vector of the robot. The grid is a matrix shown as imshow heat map with possible obstacle having high heat.

Right now, I have a code along the line shown below

```
from matplotlib import animation
from matplotlib import patches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(9,9))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

rectangle = patches.Rectangle((0,0), robo_width, robot_length,)
arrow = patches.Arrow(0,0,0,5)
img = plt.imshow(grid[0], cmap='hot', interpolation='nearest', animated=True)

def update(frame):

    rectangle.set_xy([x[frame], y[frame]])
    img.set_array(grid[frame])

    return img

animate = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, updatefig)
```

HTML(animate.to_jshtml())

With this, I can plot the robot square over the grid image to show the location of the robot. Problem is, I can not find a function similar to set_xy() for the arrow patch and can not update arrow like rectangle. Is there an update method for arrow? Is there another way to plot it?